# Equivalence relations and State transitions

Tags: equivalence-relations, automata

I was studying automata theory and I'm kind of lost in solving this problem.

> Let $R$ be a relation defined on the set of states $Q$ of a DFA as $q_1Rq_2$ if $\delta(q_1,a)=\delta(q_2,a)$ for some $a\in\Sigma$.

> Is $R$ an equivalence relation? Prove.

So to prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation, I have to show that

- $R$ is reflexive
- $R$ is symmetric
- $R$ is transitive

But since it's related to DFA, I'm not sure how to approach this problem. Some help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, the relation $R$ is reflexive and symmetric.
To see that it is not transitive, consider the three-state automaton on the picture given in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton#Closure_properties) of the Wikipedia page.

Here, we have $\delta(q_0,1) = q_0 = \delta(q_1,1)$, so that $q_0 R q_1$;
also $\delta(q_1,0) = q_2 = \delta(q_2,0)$, whence $q_1 R q_2$.
Nevertheless, **there is no** $x$ such that $\delta(q_0,x) = \delta(q_2,x)$;
this is because $\delta(q_2,x)=q_2$, for all $x$, and $\delta(q_0,x) \in \{q_0,q_1\}$.
Hence $(q_0,q_2) \notin R$ and so $R$ is not transitive.

Comment: Notice however, that a slight variation of the definition of $R$ would give an equivalence relation: suppose you fix $a \in \Sigma$ and then define $q_1Rq_2$ iff $\delta(q_1,a)=\delta(q_2,a)$. What you have is different.